# Add blockHash parameter to Polkadot.js chainState query

Tags: polkadot-js

For a Polkadot parachain (Zeitgeist) query, I need to add the block hash to get historical data. See this example:

[image: Block timestamp query]

When I try to try to run the same query in polkadot.js, I get an error when I try and add a blockHash as a parameter

// This causes an error - how to provide block hash to this function?

```
const blockHash = "0x52352ca066543d41aacb0c6419e5bb7e2d9ee621b3d8dabe2c2174ce2c5f86c5"
const unixTimestamp = await api.query.timestamp.now(blockHash);
```

could you help me figure out how I should provide this parameter?

the error:

```
ba@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.ac52cd44a2179bd7.js:1:79374
overrideNoSub@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.ac52cd44a2179bd7.js:1:91709
10589/u/</<@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.ac52cd44a2179bd7.js:1:105234
10589/u/</<@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.ac52cd44a2179bd7.js:1:105195
10589/u/<@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.ac52cd44a2179bd7.js:1:105338
anonymous/<@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/page.e64d864372c5d12b.js line 1464 > Function:4:49
anonymous@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/page.e64d864372c5d12b.js line 1464 > Function:7:67
30145/T</Z</<@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/page.e64d864372c5d12b.js:1464:1810
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For querying anything historical in polkadot-js there is the `.at` property to the `ApiPromise`.

Example:

```typescript
const block = '0x52352ca066543d41aacb0c6419e5bb7e2d9ee621b3d8dabe2c2174ce2c5f86c5'
const apiAt = await api.at(block);
const timestamp = await apiAt.query.timestamp.now();
console.log(timestamp);
```

I wrote a more in detail response on the `.at` for another user a while ago here: [PolkadotJs Api: queryMulti with different blockHashes](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7007/polkadotjs-api-querymulti-with-different-blockhashes/7032#7032)

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the following info (will try):

https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/read-storage-at/